how to trigger ngOnChanges of child component when user comes back to home page in ionic app?
In our ionic app, whenever the user comes back to the home page, we need to run method of child component to get the updated records. Since ionic caches pages, I am changing the input boolean property in ionViewWillEnter() method of the parent. But the ngOnChanges of the child component is not called. Even ionViewWillEnter() of the child is not called.

I tried ngZone.run() inside ionViewWillEnter() of the parent so that angular can detect the changes to the input property.
I tried ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges() on the child.
I tried using setter of input property in child component but that is also not called.

I am able to achieve the above requirement by emitting subject from parent and subscribing in the child component but since it is a simple parent child relationship and the components are not destroyed I am afraid it will create multiple listeners and slow down the app.
Kindly give some suggestions to fix this issue.
Parent html:
<child [selectedTab]="selectedTab" [dataReceived]="dataReceived" *ngIf="selectedTab == 'Upcoming'"></child>

Child ts:
ngOnChanges(changes:SimpleChanges){
    
    if(this.selectedTab == 'MyTab' && this.dataReceived && changes["dataReceived"].currentValue){
      this.getData();
    // });
    }
  }


Try with window popstate, maybe it might work.
@HostListener('window:popstate', ['$event'])
onPopState(event) {
     this.getData();
}

Else you can try router.events. Don't forget to unsubscribe this too, on component destroy.
...
constructor(router: Router) {
    router.events
      .subscribe((event: NavigationStart) => {
        if (event.navigationTrigger === 'popstate') {
             this.getData();
        }
      });
}
...

